# Ubuntu 20.04 starts drag&drop too soon

Tags: 20.04, mouse, gui, drag-and-drop, click-policy

Is there a way to increase the delay (the time the left mouse button must be pressed before starting drag&drop) distinguishing between a click and drag&drop? I often click on something, but Ubuntu 20.04 starts drag&drop.

Comment: Please answer your own question if you ever find out. This is a problem for me.